# DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea without Aero Glass

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, aero, dwm

Using the `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` API call with Aero Glass enabled works just fine. However, I want it to work when Aero Glass is disabled as well, like how it works in the Windows control panel:

[image]

Notice how the frame has extended into the client area, even though Aero Glass is disabled? When I make the `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` API call in my application, the returned HRESULT is definitely not success, and my application ends up looking like this:

http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/9629/clientapplication.png

Normally, with Aero Glass enabled, the border stretches down to underneath the navigation buttons, like in the control panel. How do I do this? `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` clearly isn't working.

By the way, if it is relevant, my application is a WPF application.

Answer (score 7):

Nir's answer is correct; when composition is disabled you have to draw that area yourself.

i can show you the code i have in the paint handler of the panel at the top of my form - the panel normally responsible for drawing the 0x00000000 transparent black to make the glass appear:

### **Psuedo-code:**

```
procedure DrawGlassHeaderArea(g: Graphics; r: Rectangle; IsFormFocused: Boolean);
const
   clFakeGlassColor = $00EAD1B9;  //(185, 209, 234) This is the fake foreground glass color (for use when composition is disabled)
   clFakeGlassColorUnfocused = $00F2E4D7; //(215, 228, 242) This is the fake background glass color (for use when composition is disabled)
begin
   if Dwm.IsCompositionEnabled then
   begin
      g.FillRectangle(r, 0x00000000); //fill rectangle with transparent black
   end
   else
      //Composition disabled; fake it like Microsoft does

      //The color to use depends if the form has focused or not
      Color glassColor;
      if (IsFormFocused) then
         c = clFakeGlassColor 
      else
         c = clFakeGlassColorUnfocused;

      g.FillRectangle(r, glassColor); //fill rectangle with fake color


      //Now we have to draw the two accent lines along the bottom
      Color edgeHighlight = ColorBlend(Colors.White, glassColor, 0.33); //mix 33% of glass color to white
      Color edgeShadow = ColorBlend(Colors.Black, glassColor, 0.33); //mix 33% of glass color to black

      //Draw highlight as 2nd-last row:
      g.DrawLine(edgeHighlight, Point(r.Left, r.Bottom-2), Point(r.Right, r.Bottom-2);

      //Draw shadow on the very last row:
      g.DrawLine(edgeHighlight, Point(r.Left, r.Bottom-1), Point(r.Right, r.Bottom-1);
   end;
end;
```

### Sample usage

```
procedure MyForm.PaintBox1Paint(PaintEventArgs e)
begin
   DrawGlassHeaderArea(e.Graphics, PaintBox1.ClientRectangle, this.HasFocus); 
end;
```

### Bonus Screenshot

[image]

## Update 7/9/2014

@JakePetroules was right, and i was wrong. The *"blue"* used for fake glass is **not** hard-coded into Windows. And it **is** accessible using [`GetThemeColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773397(v=vs.85).aspx).

I coded up all the available colors (`TMT_COLOR`) available for a **Window** class:

[image]

> **Note:** For more information about Classes, Parts, and States, see [**Aero Style Classes, Parts, and States**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee453680(v=vs.85).aspx)

When using:

- **Class**: `Window`
- **Part**: `WP_CAPTION`
- **State**: *n/a (StateID is not used for the **Caption** part, nor the entire **Window** class)*

and fetch the color code **propertyID**:

- **`TMT_FILLCOLORHINT`**: for when the window has focus
- **`TMT_BORDERCOLORHINT`**: for when the window does not have focus

you get the two important colors:

[image]

The pseudo-code i now use to get the fake glass color:

```
public Color GetFakeClassColor(Boolean isWindowFocused=true)
{
   static Color fakeGlass= 0x00B8D0E9; //the correct answer anyway

   if ((GetThemeAppProperties() && STAP_ALLOW_CONTROLS) == 0)
      return fakeGlass;

   hTheme = OpenThemeData(GetDesktopWindow(), "Window");
   if (hTheme = 0)
      return fakeGlass;

   Int32 propID;
   if (isWindowFocused)
       propID= TMT_FILLCOLORHINT; //The color used as a fill color hint for custom controls.
   else
       propID= TMT_BORDERCOLORHINT; //The color used as a border color hint for custom controls.

   DWORD rgb;
   if (Failed(GetThemeColor(hTheme, WP_CAPTION, 0, propID, ref rgb))
      return fakeGlass;

   Result = new Color(rgb);
}
```

In reality, since i use Delphi, my actual code is:

```
function GetFakeGlassColor(IsWindowFocused: Boolean=True): TColor;
var
    ted: TThemedElement;
    hTheme: THandle;
    propID: Integer;
    rgb: DWORD;
begin
    Result := $00B8D0E9; //the correct answer anyway

    //We can't use the ThemeServcies.ThemesEnabled, as that mistakenly checks for version 6 of the common controls library
    //Themes can be enabled without using ComCtl V6, or common controls at all
    if not ThemeServices.ThemesAvailable then
        Exit;
    if (GetThemeAppProperties and STAP_ALLOW_CONTROLS) = 0 then
        Exit;

    htheme := ThemeServices.Theme[teWindow];
    if hTheme = 0 then
        Exit;

    if IsWindowFocused then
        propID := TMT_FILLCOLORHINT //The color used as a fill color hint for custom controls.
    else
        propID := TMT_BORDERCOLORHINT; //The color used as a border color hint for custom controls.

    if Failed(GetThemeColor(hTheme, WP_CAPTION, 0, propID, {var}rgb)) then
        Exit;

    Result := rgb;
end;
```

Comment: Just to confirm: the Basic window frame colors need to be color-picked and hardcoded, right? That's what I'm currently doing in my application. I haven't found any enums that I can use for those colors.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes. With desktop composition disabled, Microsoft applications fallback to the fixed color of a "Windows Basic" theme. One might argue that the Microsoft behavior of falling back to a single hard-coded color is wrong (Microsoft design-team is the who says that is wrong - [in their UX style guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511283.aspx#theme) In my own applications i fallback to a color based on `GetSysColor(COLOR_ACTIVECAPTION)` or `COLOR_GRADIENTACTIVECAPTION`. But using a fixed color is easier - if wrong.

Comment: What does ColorBlend do, mathematically?

Comment: Actually, in this specific case, hardcoding the colors is better. The Windows 7 Basic theme does *not* respect user-assigned colors for the title bar, therefore using them will result in your app looking wrong (notice that Control Panel continues to use a blue color despite what the user picks).

Comment: @JakePetroules *"The Windows 7 Basic theme does *not* repsect user-assigned colors..."* i would argue the the Microsoft behavior of falling back to a single hard-coded color is wrong - as would the Windows UX team. Not all Microsoft developers follow the UX guidelines. As Raymond Chen often points out: people inside Microsoft are sometimes just as guilty of "doing the wrong thing" as outside developers. `ColorBlend` just does `color1*(1-mix) + color2*(mix)` (mix=0 ==> pure color1, mix=1.0 ==> pure color2)

Comment: @IanBoyd My Point was that if the title bars themselves can't change color, you may as well just hardcode the blue to maintain a consistent experience. If the goal is an extended frame, then the window color *must* match the title bar color or that effect is not correctly achieved. Opinions aside, thanks for the ColorBlend logic, but I haven't actually observed that anywhere and frankly my app looks a bit odd with it. Could you point me to an example?

Comment: @JakePetroules You are right about that - this question is about extending glass into client area and how to handle it when composition is disabled. In my head i was thinking about my applications, where the rest of the UI elements follow the "Windows" color scheme (even on Windows 2000/XP, and with composition disabled). It's wrong to base the UI on a hard-coded single *"pseudo-glass"* color, in this case, for *"fake"* glass, it needs to be that blue-grey. Unless when you're using "Windows Classic" color scheme, and not then even **Windows** uses the steel-blue color; opting for *grey*.

Comment: @IanBoyd I just realized I screwed up my previous question, too. When I said "but I haven't actually observed that anywhere and frankly my app looks a bit odd with it" I was referring to the highlight and shadow lines your code draws at the bottom of the rectangle.

Comment: Can someone please paste an example of this for WPF?

Answer (score 2):

You have to paint it to be frame-like yourself.

You have to use `DwmIsCompositionEnabled` to check if the DWM is enabled and handle `WM_DWMCOMPOSITIONCHANGED` to detect DWM state changed.

Then you have to have to separate way of drawing the window, if DWM is enabled you use `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea`, if it's disabled you draw the "frame" yourself.

I have no idea how to duplicate the Aero frame in WPF (in my app I have my own color scheme and I'm not using the Auro frame).

This is annoying but when the DWM is disabled the system falls back to XP-style drawing and none of the DWM's services work - even those that aren't related to the glass effect.

Answer (score 2):

You need to paint the window background yourself. You should not actually hard-code the colors as previous posts have suggested, but use the theme functions to retrieve them, like so (semi-pseudocode):

```
DWORD rgb;
HANDLE hTheme = OpenThemeData(GetDesktopWindow(), L"WINDOW");
GetThemeColor(hTheme, WP_CAPTION, CS_ACTIVE,
    <is active window> ? TMT_FILLCOLORHINT : TMT_BORDERCOLORHINT, &rgb);

// Can use these functions to retrieve the individual RGB values
BYTE r = GetRValue(rgb);
BYTE g = GetGValue(rgb);
BYTE b = GetBValue(rgb);
```

These colors will remain correct even if the user changes title bar colors in the control panel (unlike using COLOR_ACTIVECAPTION / COLOR_GRADIENTACTIVECAPTION). You should also check that themes are active using `IsThemeActive()` before attempting to get theme colors.

The values of the constants for quick reference:

- WP_CAPTION: 1
- CS_ACTIVE: 1
- TMT_FILLCOLORHINT: 3821
- TMT_BORDERCOLORHINT: 3822

Comment: A slightly simpler way would be to get a stock `HBRUSH` as such: `::GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_GRADIENTACTIVECAPTION)`