# Window background like title bar of windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set Windows Forms Application (C++) to have an Aero/Glass background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785733/how-to-set-windows-forms-application-c-to-have-an-aero-glass-background)

i want create a transparent window with WinApis with C++ in Windows 7 and i use VS2010 but i know how to make it transparent i can do that like this:

```
    SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE,GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0, (255 * 70) / 100, LWA_ALPHA);
```

but i want a transparent window with transparency of title bars of normal windows of windows 7

[sample http://ril.site11.com/photos/879ec4dfeaa4.png](http://ril.site11.com/photos/879ec4dfeaa4.png)

Comment: You could always read the source code for Chrome and Firefox to learn how they do it.

Comment: i want make  whole of window transparent not only title bar

Comment: This Code Project article shows you how: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15770/Vista-Goodies-in-C-Using-Glass-in-Your-UI  The keyword that you need to use when searching is **glass**

Comment: @DavidHeffernan don't put answers in comments. Make that an answer if you feel it could help (which it obviously did)

Comment: @rubenvb Well, I'm not sure a simple link to an off-site article is enough to constitute an answer. And since I know nothing about glass, beyond its name, I don't think I can add an answer with any authority.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Very well, I'll post the answer then.

Comment: Yup, the native api is demonstrated in managed code these days :)

Answer (score 0):

This web page has a great tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15770/Vista-Goodies-in-C-Using-Glass-in-Your-UI

It show you how to make a certain portion of you windows transparent, how to add text to the transparent part, and more.